# RobotJS, how to perform a shift click or command click on Mac?

Tags: robotjs

I want to do perform a mouse click while holding down the shift key on Mac.

I tried the following:

```
robot.keyToggle('shift', 'down');
robot.mouseClick();
```

However it doesn't work. The `mouseClick()` registers as a click with holding down shift.

How do I achieve a shift click in robotjs?